# Change the default output width and height in QGIS "Save map as image" feature

Tags: qgis

I need to output many snapshots of the project I'm working on in QGIS (v3.10) into reports I create. I'm currently using the 'save map as image' function which is great as it allows copy to clipboard and I can then paste maps into my report, this is great as it's really quick and I've got reports that have had up to 50 maps in previously and foresee creating even more voluminous work in the future.

Trouble is I'm having to enter the output width and output height each time, I know the exact size to perfectly fit the map into my tables in my report template (1610 x 1040px), can I set these to replace the default 977 x 920px values?

Only other workaround I can think of is setting my project canvas to the size of my report paste area (1610 x 1040px) and using the 'map canvas extent' setting in the 'save map as image' feature, can you set a custom project canvas size (I could save it as a template for future work going forward)

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use print layout where you can set the exact size ? if yes what wrong with that ? If not I suggest to try it (maybe using the Atlas functionality if you need to produce 50 map at a time)

Comment: I did but I'm afraid that adds time in the process and isn't as neat as the same map as image feature. My circumstance is that I'll make some changes to a map> copy to clipboard > paste into report then move the map, add/take away features then repeat. I repeat this many times dependant on the report I'm writing. Using the project>layout feature you've suggested would add significant time over the length of the total report. In addition I tried to write the report in the layout section to se if that is an acceptable workaround but it just doesn't have the same productivity tools as powerpoint